# How common is open carry of firearms in the USA?

Tags: usa, cultural-awareness, firearms

This winter, I am planning to go to the USA for the first time. One of my concerns is the presence of weapons in public. I just came back from Paris and the sight of armed soldiers patrolling public spaces made me very uncomfortable (I come from a country where you can live for 100 years without having seen a gun in real life). So I'm wondering, in open-carry states, can you see people carrying handguns in their belts?

Comment: Where exactly are you planning to go? The answer to this question will vary on the state.

Comment: I'm targeting desert areas and my only specific destination is California so far because it prohibits open carry, but I'm wondering about e.g. Nevada or Arizona or New Mexico.

Comment: I've lived in various US states, and visited many more,  most of which have few restrictions on open carry of firearms. In my experience, even in open carry states, very few people actually do so, and those that do are part of a very small protest movement. On the other hand, law enforcement officers are always armed.

Comment: Come to NZ. You are unlikely to see guns and it will be summer :-). As a bonus you will not see warships which do not confirm or deny they are carrying nuclear weapons :-). | What country are you from.?

Comment: for what its worth, I live in Texas and open carry is really a non-issue unless the person is trying to prove a political point. The only people who carry visible guns are, for the most part, cops.

Comment: Having been to the southwest US, you're far more likely to see scorpions and rattlesnakes than normal citizens open-carrying handguns. (And you'll be in significantly greater danger from them as well...)

Comment: @HbÖ Just so that you are aware, people who are exercising their right to open carry that doesn't make them likely shoot people or things. There are still strict laws on when you can actually _use_ those guns.

Comment: My son was disturbed by the sight of such protestors carrying "assault rifles" in fast food restaurants- I think in MO. Just because open carry is banned in California doesn't mean that there are not plenty of people carrying concealed. A friend in CA has something like 100+ guns and pretty much wouldn't think of leaving the house without one.

Comment: The soldiers carrying big scary weapons are probably the least dangerous of all- they're well-trained and the magazines are usually not in the guns. Gangbangers and bimbos with a handgun in their purse scare me more.

Comment: There's some strong variability here, too - I lived in a town in Arizona where about 1/4th of the population regularly wore a handgun on their side. We eve had gun fights in the street - of course, it was a Wild West street performance for those. But the guns on the hips everywhere were real. In the local Wal-Mart I'd see a gun carried on a hip at least once a week, and in the small rural town it was multiple times a day. Meanwhile in an urban area I haven't seen even one in 5 years now.

Comment: For those who closed as 'too broad,' can you please explain why you think this is too broad? While there may be localized exceptions, this question can be _and has been_ answered in a way applicable to the vast majority of the U.S., especially the parts that someone from out of the country is likely to visit. I would certainly not say that there "are many possible (reasonably correct) answers" or that "good answers would be too long" for this question.

Comment: I'm an American gun owner and I open carry. (Though not all the time.) It's not my gun you need to be afraid of, it's my cooking...

Comment: @HbÖ I have proposed an edit to the question title to more closely reflect what you seem to be asking in the question body and what you seem to be more concerned about judging from your comments. Hopefully this will help the question be reopened by reducing its scope. Please feel free to roll back and/or change the edit if you feel it doesn't accurate reflect what you were trying to ask.

Comment: Why this question was closed is being discussed in [this meta question](http://meta.travel.stackexchange.com/q/3201/12011). So far, it seems that the close votes stem from an erroneous conflation of open carry laws with open carry practices. Open carry laws (and gun laws in general) certainly do vary widely across the U.S., but, as discussed in the answers, open carry isn't a common practice in almost any part of the U.S., especially not in the parts that tourists are likely to visit.

Comment: The answer I would vote for is, ironically, [in a close-voter's answer to why they voted to close on meta](http://meta.travel.stackexchange.com/a/3204).

Answer (score 24, accepted):

As Jonathan's answer mentions, pretty much all police officers open carry firearms in the U.S. (pistols on their belt.) Other than that, however, seeing people visibly carry their firearms is *very* rare in the U.S. (unless you're at a gun range or some such thing.) I live in one of the most gun-friendly parts of the U.S. and I almost never see a firearm carried openly in public, other than by police. Lots of people carry firearms, but nearly all of them carry them concealed where you will not see them.

It is also very unlikely that you will see armed soldiers carrying rifles patrolling in public in the U.S. as you may have seen in France. The only times I've ever seen that in person in the U.S. were when the President was about to step off of Air Force One within sight of where I was sitting and briefly in airports after 9/11 (and ceremonially at Arlington National Cemetery, if you count that.) You will not see armed soldiers in airports nowadays, though, except in very rare situations (such as the President landing there.) Soldiers patrolling airports in the U.S. only happened for maybe a few months to a year or so after the September 11 attacks.

Comment: I don't know about airports, but I see armed soldiers in Penn Station on a daily basis. It's been a while since I've seen them carrying rifles rather than sidearms, but not *that* long — a couple years? I also used to see them in the PATH station under WTC but it's been a while since I've traveled that way.

Comment: @hobbs They are still around the PATH, but they usually only carry holstered sidearms, no larger weapons.

Comment: Guns also fit nicely in purses. But I would also add that many guns aren't necessarily ON the person. Granny with a pistol in the glove compartment, trucker with a shutgun in the door, etc.

Comment: Penn Station FWIW is a special situation directly related to national emergencies. Penn Station is a facility involved with the on-going JTF (Joint Task Force) Empire Shield. [Straight Dope](http://boards.straightdope.com/sdmb/showthread.php?t=645452) has some more information about this special circumstance.

Comment: I've seen estimates for number of concealed carry licenses varying from around 5 to 8 million. (The latest was from 2011 and hand gun sales have boomed since then, so it's fair to theorize that concealed carry licenses are probably up too.) So wherever you go in the US, there will likely be people around carrying concealed weapons. Of course the people with permits are the people who have passed background checks and are almost surely NOT a threat. The people to be afraid of are the ones who DON'T have a permit.

Comment: Also, you will not know if you're around someone with a concealed weapon, so it might not have the same nervousness factor as open-carry.

Answer (score 19):

Every single police offer in the US carries a visible firearm as a part of their uniform. Therefore it is extremely likely that you will see multiple handguns during your visit as most urban areas are regularly patrolled by policemen.

[image]

Comment: @mucaho His question suggests ANY carried firearm is an issue- viz "I just came back from Paris and the sight of armed soldiers patrolling public spaces made me very uncomfortable."

Comment: @RussellMcMahon I wouldn't conclude that without clarification from the asker. Soldiers carrying automatic rifles is a rather different proposition from police carrying sidearms. (It could be that both are unacceptable but it's also possible that the line is drawn somewhere between the two.)

Comment: The Paris armed soldiers carry big guns in their arms, which is a lot more disturbing than policemen having a gun on their belt. Our local policemen carry guns but still those guns in Paris were disturbing for me as well.

Comment: Excuse me, but what?  Police carry guns, but I certainly don't see the police every day, or even every month.  Police presence is typically the same in the US as it is in any other country.  Unless the asker is in the US for an extended period of time, he'll be unlikely to see the police.

Comment: I haven't been in Paris since the Charlie Hebdo attack, but I do remember when the Heathrow police started toting Hechler & Kochs. Sub-machine guns carried in "port arms" position in crowded terminals made me very nervous, far more than holstered handguns. How exactly would you _use_ one of those things, and if they do single-shot, okay, but what happens if you have the whatsit in the wrong position and open fire? So I sympathise with the OP, military arms at airports are indeed more scary. Though I have just come back from where bank guards carry Kalashnikovs.....

Comment: Like @DavidPugh I have a very distinct memory of the first time I saw police at a London airport carrying sub-machine guns. For those of us in countries with strict gun control, it's a somewhat disturbing sight, however necessary.

Comment: @DavidPugh has there been a single incident where an innocent civilian in the Western world was injured by a sub-machine gun fired by a government employee?

Comment: @SteveSether most popular tourist sites in Europe are patrolled by police officers. I assume the same applies in the US.

Comment: Yes, I'm okay with uniformed officers with a handgun, it's pretty normal in most places (sometimes with a non-lethal variant weapon instead). It's soldiers in full camo suits with assault rifles that make me uncomfortable.

Comment: @Jonathan: Dunno. OP, I and others were talking impressions, not statistics. Almost stepped on a Swiss snake today; found out he was harmless, but he still gave me a nasty turn.

Comment: "Every single police offer in the US carries a visible firearm as a part of their uniform." Well, that's not quite true. MANY, probably MOST, police officers in the US carry visible firearms. But not all. For example, the DARE officer in my old home town didn't carry a gun. (DARE=police-run program to encourage kids not to use drugs)

Comment: @SteveSether location matters. In my former life, I felt the same way. Working in Manhattan, hardly a day goes by when I don't see *multiple* NYPD.

Comment: @HbÖ As mentioned in my answer, you're very unlikely to see soldiers in full camo carrying assault rifles in public areas in the U.S. except for very rare situations like when the President is visiting, so there's not really much to worry about there.

Comment: @AE It's a fairly disturbing site for those of us that live in areas with much more lax gun control, too. Seeing a rifle on a gun range or while hunting is one thing. Seeing police or military carrying rifles/carbines/SMGs in crowded public areas is quite another.

Comment: @DavidPugh The rifle in question is, [according to Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_police_firearms_in_the_United_Kingdom#Carbines.2C_Shotguns.2C_and_Rifles) the Heckler and Koch MP5SF. That's a single fire semi-automatic weapon: pulling the trigger fires a single round and the mechanism automatically chambers the next round but you have to pull the trigger again to fire that. There is no full auto (hold the trigger and spray bullets) mode so there's no whatsit that could be in the wrong place.

Comment: @JonathanReez As someone else said, location matters.  I've travelled throughout Europe and have spent a considerable amount of time in Rome.  I hardly ever see the police in Rome around tourist attractions, and have hardly ever seen them throughout other tourist attractions in Spain, the UK, and Germany.  I've travelled the US extensively as well, and hardly ever see the police at touristy places.  Maybe Yellowstone?  But certainly not at museums.

Comment: @SteveSether Certainly you don't see the police often _within_ tourist attractions in the U.S., but you will see them fairly frequently driving around in their patrol cars in urban areas or perhaps stopped by the road to write someone a parking or speeding ticket. The only 'touristy' place I can think of in the U.S. where police or other armed guards are very likely to be standing around is Washington, D.C., especially at the Capitol building and other such government buildings frequented by the President or members of Congress.

Comment: @reirab Again, depends; for instance, the officer in the picture is a US Park Police officer, and the Park Police is an entire police force that *specializes* in patrolling touristy areas in DC, NYC, and San Francisco (in addition to some more regular patrol work in the DC area). You're also likely to see cops around at airports. (incidentally, the DC area has cops at lots of buildings that aren't frequented by high government officials as well; for instance, all Smithsonian museums have armed guards at the entrances).

Comment: @cpast Good point about airports. I agree about D.C. I just meant that there are more of them at places frequented by high-level officials. Pretty much anything that's considered a reasonably likely target of an attack will have more police presence, though, like you said, in most cases that's more at the entrance than milling about within an attraction.

Answer (score 13):

It is extremely unlikely that you will ever run across a normal citizen walking around with a gun strapped to their belt, even in open-carry states.

You will see police officers with guns strapped to their belts, that's about all you're likely to see.

There's a lot of over-hyped media attention to open-carry laws, and during some protests, pro-gun owners will make a point of exercising their constitutional right to carry firearms by bringing their guns out in public in a non-threatening manner. However this is extremely rare, and can be easily avoided by just avoiding conservative/right-wing political demonstrations. (Not that you'd be in any danger, whatsoever).

Comment: I agree that those protest are rare, but I also wouldn't call them entirely nonthreatening. I know that's the claim made by the protesters, and that they don't intend to directly threaten anyone, but in places where people don't expect to see guns, someone carrying a gun can easily be perceived as threatening. The OP's discomfort with seeing guns in public spaces is a perfect demonstration of this.

Comment: Whether a person FEELS threatened is not the same as whether he IS threatened. To the best of my knowledge, no one in the United States has ever been shot by people who were participating in a pro-gun rally or protest. (If you can find a case or two, they're extremely rare.) I suspect you are far safer at such a rally than pretty much any place else on earth, as even the truly insane criminals seem to have figured out that attacking someone at a place where you KNOW that there are hundreds of armed people around is a very bad idea.

Comment: @MarkDanielJohansen  re " ...  no one in the United States has ever been shot by people who were participating in a pro-gun rally or protest. ..." -> Probably true, I imagine. But far more people innocent people have been shot on a "number shot per group member" basis by people from the group "have on one or more occasion attended a pro-gun rally protest as a protestor" than from the group "whole US population except 1st group". ie innocent people (including shooter's friends and family) are far more at risk from such people than from the average citizen. ....

Comment: .... I believe the preceding  is a very well demonstrated fact. Am I wrong?

Comment: @RussellMcMahon It would be tough to get statistics on that, as it would require identifying and tracking all the people who have attended such a rally. But I just did some searching for statistics, and here's the first thing I found: A 2002 study by the state of Minnesota on crimes committed by people with permits to carry a concealed weapon. Feel free to read it yourself: https://dps.mn.gov/Pages/Results.aspx?k=crime%20ccw Bottom line: they have a total of 11,381 people in the state with concealed-carry licenses. Of those, number who were convicted of any crime: 4. ...

Comment: ... Two for drunk driving, one for assault, one for speeding. Number who used a firearm in the commission of a crime: Zero. Sounds like an all-around pretty safe and law-abiding group to me. Disclosure: I have a license to carry a concealed weapon, have for, umm, probably 10 years, so I'm not claiming to be a disinterested observer. I don't carry a gun all that often. Unless you're a mugger reading this, in which case, I always carry my .357 magnum.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon "I believe the preceding is a very well demonstrated fact. Am I wrong?" Almost certainly. The vast majority of firearm murders in the U.S. are due to drug dealers/drug users/gangs, which are definitely _not_ the people who hang out at pro-gun rallies.

Comment: @reirab Your comment may be correct - but it's not what I asked about. I was not talking about murders or criminal elements but about the statistical likelihood of being shot. ie the "assertion" implies that if a gun owner who actively carries and/or uses a gun for protection is a friend or family member or neighbor or workmate or regular contact then your chances of being innocently shot increases. ie having such people in your community increases (rather than decreases) the prospect of you being shot as an innocent. More so if they are a family member than a casual contact.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon Ah, you said earlier shot _by_ the person who owns the gun, which was the source of my misunderstanding. As far as I know, the statistic you're referring to is almost entirely due to suicide or people (other than the gun owner) accidentally shooting themselves. Mostly the former.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon that's not a very useful statistic (if it even is one), it's like saying. You're more likely to be hit by a car living nearby someone with a car. Or, you're more likely to die in an earthquake if you move to California. Sure, statistically that may be true, but it doesn't really have anything to do with the topic at hand.

Answer (score 4):

To add a case not mentioned yet: in many rural parts of the US, hunting is legal and popular.  I'd include rural areas of Arizona, New Mexico and Nevada in that list (California less so).  If you travel in those areas, and especially if you spend time outdoors in certain public lands such as national forests, you are likely to see gun racks on trucks, meet hunters carrying rifles and shotguns, and hear gunshots.   Handguns are still less likely, though.

Comment: The distinction between US National Parks, National Forests and other designations probably isn't obvious to most (especially to non-Americans); this [PBS article](http://www.pbs.org/wnet/nature/river-of-no-return-national-parks-national-forests-and-u-s-wildernesses/7667/) has a good summary. In particular, hunting is prohibited in National *Parks*, whose purpose is conservation, but not in National *Forests*, whose purpose is resource management.

Comment: Pennsylvania has the largest hunting population in the country.  It is common to have children take off school the first day of hunting season.

Answer (score 4):

You mentioned Arizona.  I don't live there anymore, but I grew up in Arizona and lived there for over 25 years.  I hardly ever saw people openly carrying guns.  Every now and then I'd see someone with a gun on their belt, it was not common- maybe a couple of times a year.  You could probably visit Arizona for a month and not see anybody carrying a gun, other than police officers, of course.  On the other hand, in some cases, gun owners in Arizona can get a permit to carry concealed weapons.  So you really never know who has a gun with them and who doesn't.

After the terrorist attacks on September 11, 2001, I did see armed soldiers for a while in places like airports in Texas, Colorado, Tennessee, etc.  However, I think that has pretty much been phased out for the most part.  I haven't seen any soldiers like that in years.

Comment: It may not be common in Arizona, but you will see open carry there more than other states, I think. When I lived in Phoenix I'd see someone with a pistol in the grocery store every other week or so. Open carry is technically OK here in Colorado too, but I hardly ever see it.

Answer (score 0):

It is generally recognized that concealed carry is advantageous to open carry in public. Most gun owners who carry, do so concealed. In all honesty, you will most likely be around guns, but will not see them. Most of the time, people that tend to carry openly (in urban areas), do so when they do not have a concealed carry permit.

[Source](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/47490/how-common-are-firearms-in-usa-exactly/47504#47504)

Comment: This looks like [quotation-needed] now.